# Better Approach to Parse a common Json and insert it into DB

Tags: android, json, web-services, parsing

I have two webservices which return similar type of data like :

Data1:

```
{
    "FailedValidations": null,
    "IsSuccess": true,
    "Message": null,
    "Result": [
        {
            "IsMandatory": true,
            "ModuleCode": 23,
            "ModuleID": 37,
            "Name": "Availability Index",
            "ParentModuleID": null,
            "Sequence": 0,
            "UserID": 0,
            "UserRoleID": 0
        }]}
```

Data 2:

```
{
    "FailedValidations": null,
    "IsSuccess": true,
    "Message": null,
    "Result": [
        {
            "ModuleCode": 23,
            "ModuleID": 37,
            "Name": "Availability Index",
            "Questions": [
                {
                    "DealerTypes": null,
                    "IsActive": true,
                    "ModuleCode": 19,
                    "ModuleID": 33,
                    "Options": [
                        {
                            "IsActive": true,
                            "OptionValue": "Yes",
                            "Sequence": 1,
                            "SurveyOptionID": 45581,
                            "SurveyQuestionID": 54751
                        },
                        {
                            "IsActive": true,
                            "OptionValue": "No",
                            "Sequence": 2,
                            "SurveyOptionID": 45582,
                            "SurveyQuestionID": 54751
                        }
                    ],
            "Sequence": 0
        }
```

what I did is , I have created single DTO class to parse these both data by using GSON library . like :

```
    private int UserID;
    private boolean IsMandatory;
    private int Sequence;
    private int ModuleID;
    private int ModuleCode;
    private String ModuleIcon;
    private boolean isQuestionType;
    private boolean isStoreWise;
    private String ParentModuleID;
    private String UserRoleID;
    private String Name;
    private ArrayList<Question> Questions;
```

and insert theses data in data1  and data2 tables in DB.

> The above approach works fine but i just want to know :
>
> 1.Is this the best approach to parse two similar(almost) json.
>
> 2.Or If I create two DTO for each json data is the best approach.

Which is the best approach from above two and why?? or is there any other way to do this(besides manual parsing).

Comment: So you have `List<Option>` in `Question` class ??

Comment: I think you have try to manual parsing json data from response and store database in same table now problem is result json data is differ so try to store result as simple string in database and when you need it just make JsonArray from this string.

Comment: @R9J -  yes i have List<Option> in my Question Class

Comment: What about your parsing methods? where did you located it?

Comment: @Haresh- what i did is working fine for me,it's nothing to do with storing results, as i am saving results specific values in my both tables.

Comment: @R9J- my parsing methods is simple like : `g.fromJson(response, MyClass.class);`